# list index out of range when the code still works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python and I've been working on an algorithm that involves genetic code. I started by associating all 4 genetic bases, A, C, T, G with a list. A is 1,0,0,0. C is 0,1,0,0. T is 0,0,1,0 and G is 0,0,0,1. There are two different genetic codes, one being the original one and the other being one that was genetically mutated. The algorithm is going to come to conclusions of the data given based on the difference between the two genetic codes. But first, I need to sort of preprocess the data before I can work on the algorithm making conclusions.

The code looks like this so far:

```
A = [1, 0, 0, 0]
C = [0, 1, 0, 0]
T = [0, 0, 1, 0]
G = [0, 0, 0, 1]
original = [A, T, T, G, C, T, A]
copy = [C, T, T, A, T, A, A]
final = original
for i, v in enumerate(original):
    if v == copy[i]:
        print(v)
    elif v != copy[i]:
        final.insert(i, 1)
        print(final)
```

The error that I'm getting is that "index is out of range". However, the program still runs but the error shows up. Firstly, should I be worried about this in the first place and does it mean anything? Second, if it is a big deal, how should I fix this? If it's not, why is it happening in the first place? I also tried different code compliers like google collab and Pycharm.
[image]

I'm fairly new to Python so there could be something small I'm overlooking. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The program only runs until it encounters the error. then it throws the error and does not run anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `final` and `original` point to same location in memory. So when you inserted values to `final` at this line of code:

```
final.insert(i, 1)
```

... `original` variable got also reflected and in the end there was no value at the `i`th location in `copy` here:

```
if v == copy[i]:
```

**Solution**:

You have create a copy of list:

```
final = original[:]
# or: final = original.copy()
```

Comment: I would even say `final = original.copy()` for clarity.

Comment: @Guimoute, although that would be a personal preference, I just added to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is this line:

```
final = original
```

You may be thinking that `final` is a new list which contains the same values as `original`. But in fact, it refers to the *same* list.

Now, in this loop,

```
for i, v in enumerate(original):
        # ...
        final.insert(i, 1)
```

you not only modify the `final` list, but, since it's actually the *same* list, also `original`. Therefore, the iteration over `original` is extended and leads to values of `i` which are larger than what is allowed as index for the `copy` list (which originally had the same size as `original`).

Therefore you get the error "List index out of range" for the line `if v == copy[i]`, which effectively means that `i` has become larger than `len(copy) - 1`.

To avoid this error, you need to create `final` as an actual copy of `original`, which you can do by

```
final = original[:]
```

or

```
final = list(original)
```

See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) for even more options.